# getting issue while running large psql query on EC2 instance

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, pgadmin

I have psql query which take one key at a time and keep updating other record in table.
like below

```
DO $$ 
DECLARE 
    i INT;
BEGIN
    FOR i IN 1..10 LOOP
        -- here we have 27 query's to run (insert, delete, update)
        -- Update multiple rows for key(i)
        -- each query takes near about 30 min to run it might because of large data (500GB)
        -- we are doing commit after each query to release memory (let us know is this best way to do       this)

    END LOOP;
END $$;
```

issue is while running this query at some point query get stuck but on pgAdmin its shows running, how to handle this issue.

1. tried commit after every query to release memory
2. running individual query gives proper response
3. added indexing for better performance

Comment: Impossible to answer since you don't share code, nor results from `explain(analyze, verbose, buffers)` for the individual queries. By the way, most likely you don't need a loop. Rewrite your code to work in sets. That's how SQL works anyway.

Comment: If this is ec2, not rds, then use `top` to see what the server is doing from the OS perspective.  either way, use pg_stat_activity to see what is doing from the PostgreSQL perspective.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a difficult issue to troubleshoot via Stackoverflow. However, if the individual queries work without any issues, I would recommend extracting the loop from the query into the code that executes the query, so that the each query is executed individually.